# What is this soil digging insect?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

It is in Texas(Month: May). Are these flying ants?termites? or Cicada Killers?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not cicada killers--those have yellow stripes on them, are considerably larger, and also have a very different shape of abdomen. Here's a good pic of one of those: https://bugguide.net/node/view/1721236/bgimage.
They certainly look to have a hymenopteran "waist" so that means they aren't termites, they are some kind of winged ant. Possibly carpenter ants due to the large size (for ants) and the reddish-brown color (like this one https://bugguide.net/node/view/1056576/bgimage).